# Why isn't this SVG animation working cross-browser?

Tags: google-chrome, animation, svg, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I have an SVG image generated for me by www.loading.io, and the animation is only working on Google Chrome (v. 48). I have tried opening the file in Internet Explorer 11, Firefox (v. 44), and Edge (v. 25), and they only render the initial image without any animation. [Example](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9F7FCE5CCA52BABF!34000&authkey=!ADKrffrwwMO5ljU&ithint=video%2Cmp4). You can observe the behavior for yourself as well by downloading the SVG [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9F7FCE5CCA52BABF!34003&authkey=!ALyYwubcFXoHiFQ&ithint=file%2Csvg).

Here is the SVG markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg width='50px' height='50px' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"
     class="uil-ring">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" class="bk"></rect>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="46" stroke-dasharray="145.95839468578177 143.06812944447918" stroke="#285e8c" fill="none"
            stroke-width="8">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 50 50;180 50 50;360 50 50;"
                          keyTimes="0;0.5;1" dur=".75s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0s"></animateTransform>
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Does anyone know how I can get this nice little SVG to animate on all modern browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SMIL specification says that [durations cannot start with a . character](https://www.w3.org/TR/SMIL20/smil-timing.html#Timing-ClockValueSyntax) - a leading zero is required and that's what Firefox implements. I've corrected things below so it works in Firefox.

IE does not support SMIL although the [fakeSmile library](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) can be used to overcome that.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg width='50px' height='50px' viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"
     class="uil-ring">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="none" class="bk"></rect>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="46" stroke-dasharray="145.95839468578177 143.06812944447918" stroke="#285e8c" fill="none"
            stroke-width="8">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 50 50;180 50 50;360 50 50;"
                          keyTimes="0;0.5;1" dur="0.75s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="0s"></animateTransform>
    </circle>
</svg>
```